# Using picasso on a Galaxy S4 and S8 image does not appear on S8

Tags: android, picasso, galaxy

Testing both the S8 and the S4 in debug mode I get the following in the Android Studio Console on the S8 and the image fails to display:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@182d6d5[GetEncounters]: 
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@182d6d5[GetEncounters]: 
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream 
returned null
D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream 
returned null
D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream 
returned null
D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream 
returned null
D/TcpOptimizer: [com.pottssoftware.woodyplants] 
Full closed: sid=92, tcpi_state=8
V/NativeCrypto: SSL shutdown failed: 
ssl=0x7f65fb37c8: I/O error during system call, 
Broken pipe
D/ViewRootImpl@182d6d5[GetEncounters]: 
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@182d6d5[GetEncounters]: 
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

On the S4 from the console I get:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage 
ACTION_DOWN
E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current 
context (logged once per thread)
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage 
ACTION_DOWN
W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved 
from android.provider.Settings.System to 
android.provider.Settings.Global, returning 
read-only value.
```

The android version on the S8 is 7.0 on the S4 the version is 5.0.
There are no app permissions on the S8.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue a while ago, pictures taken on some phones would not display.
In the end I switched to using Glide, which does essentially the same as Picasso with an almost identical syntax.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide